# How to skip header and footer when processing a flat file using Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have my file as following,

```
CustomerDetails~NorthSector~Detail~Alex~12~Mark~55~Helen~33~Andrew~67~Footer~page1
```

I need to capture the data between ***Detail*** and ***Footer***. and put them in my db. The detail inbetween represent the customer  name and age. How can I use flatitemreader to achieve this. Or do I have to write a custom reader.

Answer (score 0):

This file format is very specific. I see no obvious way to read it with the `FlatFileItemReader`.

A custom `ItemReader` is probably a better option for this use case.